# Parsing a string on whitespace with the assign, substring, and find methods

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I would like to parse a string using whitespace as delimiters.  I know it can be done using 3 methods from the string library, `assign`, `substring`, and `find` . Basically I want to assign my target string the substring from the beginning of the string to the first occurrences of whitespace.

It would be something like this

```
while(!line.empty())
{

    line.assign(line.substr(0, line.find(" ")
    line.erase(0, line.find(" ");

}
```

My question is, would this be a good way to go about parsing a string?

Comment: Unless I'm reading this wrong, you might want to add an extra `)` or two on each of those `line.` lines. :)

Comment: This is heavily commented on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need a bit more than just one `line` variable: as is your code won't terminate if the string contains a non-space character. Of course, this assumes that it compiles in the first place as there are a number of parenthesis and a semicolon missing (also, your question doesn't match your code: there is no function `substring`; if you want to program effectively, you have to be very precise about *everything*: computer take your statements very literal). You probably want to chop your `line` up into its bits and put them into some sort of container.

Once over these trivial aspect, you might want to consider using `' '` instead of `" "` because in this case the compiler and library can assume that you want to look for just one character rather than for a sequence of characters. This can be quite a bit faster. However, this is actually not *whitespace* but just space. Whitespace also includes a number of special characters like `'\t'` (tab), `'\r'` (carriage return), `'\n'` (newline), `'\v'` (vertical tab), `'\b'` (backspace), and `'\f'` (form feed). Speaking of speed you probably don't want to `erase()` bits from the beginning of the string as this yield an O(n * n) algorithm while this can be done O(n) e.g. by keeping a variable with the position. This also avoid the problem of searching twice which is unnecessary expensive. You should also consider the behavior if there are two adjacent strings: should this produce an empty string in your sequence or should this be treated as if there were one space (in which case you might want to also use `first_not_of()`).

Actually, I just reread the problem statement: if you just want to extract the string up to the first space, you don't need `erase()`, `empty()`, or a loop if you insist on using `assign()`. However, this can be done using even two `std::string` members: `find()` and `erase()`:

```
line.erase(line.find(" \t\r\n\v\b\f"));
```